# Why is Comparable parameterized?

Tags: java

Since [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) exports only one function and since [that function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) accepts only one parameter that is of type "this" (The class that implements Comparable), why is Comparable parameterized?  Given that Comparable is used for natural ordering, why would anyone pass a class different from the one that implements this interface?

Comment: Lacked a couple of question marks :))

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's useful when you think of what's *consuming* it. For example:

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

That way you can call `item.compareTo(otherItem)` in a type-safe way, so long as both are `T`.

Likewise when *implementing* it, you can write:

```
public int compareTo(MyClass other)
```

instead of having to use:

```
public int compareTo(Object other)
```

and then casting.

So yes, it would be very odd to implement `Comparable<SomethingElse>` - but there's no other way of referring to "the type which is implementing this interface" in a generic way, and it's useful to be able to express the "other" part cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

You can have two types `X` and `Y` that are both `Comparable<B>`. As long as both `X` and `Y` extend (or implement `B`) you can freely cross-compare those objects.

Theoretically you could even write a class `W` that's `Comparable<V>`. That would mean that you can compare it to `V` but *not* to other instances of `W`. I can't at the moment think of a good use-case for that, but it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, It's the only way to say that T is Comparable to itself.

They could have added some shorthand to express this much I suspect it wouldn't have been any shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Rajikumar, you already answered your question. Comparable is generic to garantee type safety and make sure you are giving an argument of the right type, which is the class implementing Comparable.

Answer (score 0):

With this parameters you dont need to use the instanceof operator.

The Comparable is often used to compare if the instance of an object is the correspond to another instance. Exemple, if you want to now if a DogA is the same of DogB, you know that no one is a cat. So you never will see if a Cat is a Dog because they have diferente origins. This